# Yellow screen freeze with Radeon HD 5450 running Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, drivers, ati, radeon

This is my PC Configuration:

```
Core 2 Duo E4500
2 GB DDR2
Intel DG41RQ (GMA x4500)
WD 500 GB HDD
400W PSU
AMD Radeon HD 5450
```

Yesterday I installed a Radeon HD 5450 card and I have installed the closed source Radeon drivers after downloading the package from the AMD website (version 12.1).

The essential settings have been taken care of but I have having a weird problem. Every time I shut down the system I get a yellow screen and the system freezes. While I restart I do get the yellow screen but the computer eventually reboots after a couple of seconds.

I don't think the card is faulty because it works perfectly with Windows, It's handling games and stuff. I don't think the driver is broken because I am using it on another machine with Radeon HD 6790. Is it the kernel or some setting that I'm missing ??

PS: I am using a 3.2.7-custom kernel.

Cheers,

UTSAV